# Does selenium web driver supports Node.js and Vue.js?

Tags: node.js, selenium, vue.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Does selenium web driver support Node.js and Vue.js ? or Do we need to use any plugins to support them?if yes,please name the plugins?

Comment: Could you please specify in which way you need selenium to support nodejs and vuejs?

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is a free (open source) automated testing suite for web applications across different browsers and platforms. Primarily it is used for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.

Having said that, when using *Selenium* [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you need not worry about the *Application* stack or the technologies involved as *Selenium* interacts with the elements within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

So to conclude, irrespective of the AUT's underlying technology stack being built through [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) or [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), the main focus is how the [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) are represented within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).